# how to put array of download URLs of images to viewpager

Tags: android, arrays, android-viewpager, imageview, firebase-storage

I made a view pager with an image view inside it, and I want to make something like an image slider using the view pager. I have an array of download URLs. how can i put those URLs to open the image to the image view. I tried searching for other tutorials but they all use bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Global Array to store URLs and than display using GLide Like>>>

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

        ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

        final ProgressBar pbLoad = view.findViewById(R.id.pbLoad);

        String image = images.get(position);

        imageViewPreview.setTag(image);

  Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image).thumbnail(0.5f).crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imageViewPreview);



        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: getActivity() for context in fragment. You can normally use **this** instead of that.